# Auto increment get reset to 0 at every service restart

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

It worked until now but when i restart the service, the database lost the auto-increment value for my table. It's for sure something i do with my queries, because i didn't modified my tables recently. What could it be?

Comment: get a list of all stored procedures and triggers you have on your DB. Check it for something suspicious. Try re-installing the server see if that helps

Comment: no triggers, no procedures, it happens only on service restart, it works perfectly if i truncate the table and start over.

Comment: By service restart you mean that you restart the mysql-server ?

Answer (score 3):

That is the documented behaviour, it's not a bug.
When the server starts up, it goes through each (InnoDB) table determining what the new auto_increment value should be.  From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html :

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server runs. When the
>   server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes the counter for each table for the
>   first INSERT to the table, as described earlier.

It does something similar when you deploy DDL that causes a table rebuild, such as altering the `engine` -- even altering it to the same value it was before.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it'd be zero.

Answer (score -1):

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MyISAM

Works for me. InnoDB stores the AI in memory, so it's reset to current number of rows + 1 when mysql server is restarted. So if your table is empty when you restart the server, it will be reset to 1.

MyISAM on the other hand was well built.